# Menu dropdown like facebook buttons

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for some tutorial or explanation about how to make a menu like the 3 buttons of facebook ("Friends,Notification,Messages"). I would like create something like that when you click on element it show a menu, and when you click outside the element this close. I tried to search on google without success for a lot of time. Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be lengthy! But do read it to last.

Facebook and Google and many other websites use jQuery for this purpose. Have a look at this:

**The code to hide show the divs:**

`<div class="friends" style="display: none;">Friends</div>

 <div class="messages" style="display: none;">Messages</div>

 <div class="notifications" style="display: none;">Notifications</div>`

All of these are hidden. They will be shown when they are click on, use jQuery:

`$(document).ready(function() {

   $(this).show();

  })

   $(".friends").blur(function() {  // hide on blur

   $(this).hide();

  }`

You might want to learn some more here: [jQuery OFFICIAL Site](http://jquery.com/), or here: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp).

**Ajax to load the data:**

Then comes the main idea, you want the divs to get populated with data too. For that you might want to read the Ajax jQuery.

**Example of Ajax request:**

`$.ajax({

  url: "any_link_to_page",

  data: "mainly_the_query_strings",

  success: function(result) {

    $("some_div_class_or_id").html(result);

   }

 })`

The div that should be used in ajax, must be the div that you want to get populated; the div from those 3!

The div will be populated by the data that's achieved as the results of the request.

Here is a tutorial link: [jQuery Ajax - Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

**CSS Trianlges:**

If you want to get the triangles too, you should read this: [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

The code that they are using is:

`.arrow-up {

    width: 0;

    height: 0;

    border-left: 5px solid transparent;

    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 5px solid black;

}`

Arrow up is the class for that div or span, that will be converted into a triangle.

I hope you get the basic idea. Thats all that I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

it's basically based on the show/hide thing:
you have a menu with diffrent items ID ou class

and a container colled to the menu:
like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="notifications">menu item 1</li>
    <li>menu item 2</li>
    <li>menu item 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu_notifications" class="menu_content">your content</div>
</div>
```

of course you style ur html like you want
and then if ur familiar with javascript or jquery you can bind the show hide methodes to the menu items to show and hide the cmenu content divs